# Leave the new Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Each time I log in to Google Drive, it loads the new Google Drive. I switch to the old version, and then the next time it loads the new Google Drive again.

Is the anyway to leave the new Google Drive for good without it getting back all the time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not possible anymore to switch to the old Google Drive UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there is - you should assume that sooner or later the "new" Google Drive will just be "the" Google Drive, and the old one will no longer be available.    Choosing not to upgrade (ie to stay with the old version) is not really an option when using on-line services instead of applications that you install.